# Undocumented swagger error - 404 status code

Tags: swagger

I have a .net core API with a swagger documentation and my API have a middleware to thrown exceptions with error status code and a error message.In IIS server(after publish) works perfect, swagger shows the status code and error message, but in debug mode when i throw an exception with status code 404 (only status code 404, others status code works), the swagger return is that: "Undocumented Error:" (Does not show status code and error message).

Do I have to do some additional configuration in visual studio so that the exception is displayed correctly in debug mode?

Comment: When you see "Undocumented Error", is there any error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools? This could be a CORS issue or somthing else that's blocking the request.

Comment: Failed to load resource: dapise.pulirofa.com/…0OjQ0MzA3&ns=true:1  the server responded with a status of 401 ()
Failed to load resource: dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track:1  the server responded with a status of 439 ()
Failed to load resource: 44307/v1/user/retrieve-password/W:1 the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Failed to load resource: :44307/v1/user/retrieve-password/W:1 net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Obs: this error only occurs when my API returns 404 error status code